# Exiting While Loop After User Enters Value in String (Java)

Tags: java, string, validation, input, while-loop

Hello fellow StackOverflowers, I hope all of your days are going well.

I'm relatively new to Java programming and have found myself in a bit of pickle.

What I'm attempting to do is;

1. Input Validation in Java - I want to make sure that the JOptionPane.showInput pane continues to re-appear (using a while loop) until the user has entered a value which is captured in the "this.accountName" String and;
2. From there once the user has entered something in the JOptionPane.showInput pane I want to exit the loop and proceed to the other methods I have inside my OO program.

Unfortunately my while loop below exits after the first instance and doesn't continue in my code example below;

```
public String getAccountName() {
    this.accountName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter a nick name for your new account (e.g. Savings Account)");
    if (this.accountName!= null) {
        while (this.accountName != null) {
            this.accountName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Error! Please enter a valid name for your new account");
            if (this.accountName.contains("")){return this.accountName;
            }
        }
    }
        return this.accountName;
}
```

What would be the best way to go about fixing this?
I appreciate your help in advance!

Comment: Might want to rethink this class. getters should not mutate the state of the instance.

Comment: This 'if (this.accountName.contains(""))' will always return true, unless accountName is null and in such case it will throw NullPointerException.

Comment: You should probably check if the dialog result is empty or just white space as well. Try `this.accountName!= null && this.accountName.trim().length() != 0`

Answer (score 0):

Use StringUtils.isBlank method (https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html) to check accountName value:

```
this.accountName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter a nick name for your new account (e.g. Savings Account)");
while (StringUtils.isBlank(this.accountName)) {
    this.accountName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Error! Please enter a valid name for your new account");
}
return this.accountName;
```